# Channel Image - get detailed image by ID

Tags: channel-images

I want to get the image detail by its ID  rather than the URL.
Here is my code that is not working.

List page
{exp:channel:entries channel="gallery"}

```
{gallery_images}
 <li>  
<a href="/gallery/detail/{image:id}/"><img src="{image:url:medium}" class="img" alt="{image:title}"></a>
 </li>
{/gallery_images}
```

{/exp:channel:entries}

Detailed Page

{exp:channel:entries channel="gallery"}
 {exp:channel_images:images  segment_3="{image:id}"}

{/exp:channel_images:images}

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would do the detail page:

```
{exp:channel_images:images image_id="{segment_3}"}
{image:url}
{/exp:channel_images:images}
```

Another choice if you have a variable called image already is to do this:

```
{exp:channel_images:images image_id="{segment_3}" prefix="ci"}
{ci:url}
{/exp:channel_images:images}
```

Brad

Comment: Thanks. It is now working. If i wrapped the Channel entry tag around it, it stops working. Any workaround for this?

Comment: Possibly you have a field named "image" or something? This could cause variable collision. Giving an alternative in my answer.